# How to convert a dynamic object to JSON string c#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following dynamic object that I'm getting from a third party library:

```
IOrderStore os = ss.GetService<IOrderStore>();
IOrderInfo search = os.Orders.Where(t => t.Number == "test").FirstOrDefault();
IOrder orderFound = os.OpenOrder(search, true);

dynamic order = (dynamic)orderFound;
dynamic requirements = order.Title.Commitments[0].Requirements;
```

I need to parse it to a JSON string.

I tried this (using JSON.net):

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requirements);
return jsonString;
```

But I get a seemingly corrupted JSON string, as below:

> [{"$id":"1"},{"$id":"2"},{"$id":"3"},{"$id":"4"},{"$id":"5"},{"$id":"6"},{"$id":"7"},{"$id":"8"},{"$id":"9"},{"$id":"10"},{"$id":"11"},{"$id":"12"},{"$id":"13"},{"$id":"14"},{"$id":"15"}]

The object contains multiple properties, and not just the 'id'.

Any advice?

Comment: show your object in which you want to convert

Comment: 'string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);'

Comment: @RashidJaved this is eactly what I am doing...

Comment: @HiteshThakor do you want me to show the object I want to assign the json?

Comment: @user3378165 - yes please show the way `Requirements` is created because when just simply testing a list of dynamic objects and each with several fields they are all serialized

Comment: Have you tried creating a `JObject` from your `orderFound` object, and then serializing that instead? E.g. `dynamic order = new JObject(orderFound); var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);`

Comment: @GiladGreen I can't show you how the `Requirements` object is created becasue I don't have that, I'm getting it from a third party library.

Comment: @user3378165 What type is your `orderFound` object, and why are you casting it to a `dynamic`? Could you show us that object?

Comment: So try and show it from debug.. or somehow.. because `JsonConvert` does work on a list of dynamic objects with several properties..

Comment: What you are trying to do looks perfectly correct. See [this working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w3gjn4). We _need_ to see the decalaration/definition of the `Requirements` property in order to help you.

Comment: @user3378165 - So, I might be missing the point; but have you tried just `SerializeObject()` on your `orderFound` object, rather than the dynamic one? As already stated - `dynamic` objects *should* still serialize just fine. My only thought in this case, is that the casting to `dynamic` is just flattening the `orderFound` somehow and it's getting serialized incorrectly. Just try serializing the `orderFound` to JSON string and let us know the result?

Comment: @user3378165, sorry, but your edits don't help. What does `Console.WriteLine(order.Title.Commitments[0].Requirements.GetType());` print? Show us that string, please. Also, you keep saying you are using a third party library. Which library? Is there documentation available? And most importantly: how you you know the returned JSON is "_corrupted_", as you say? What is your reference? What _exactly_ do you expect to see?

Comment: @Abbondanza It gives me an internal object of the third party library, it's a third party that we are working with without any relation to programming and in term of security I can't mention. There is a documentation, and they told me to use `dynamic`. When I tried to get rid of the `dynamic` I got a bounch of errors from their API. If I do use `dynamic` I can explicity access the properties but when I try to serialize it to JSON I get only the 'id' property, so maybe 'corrupted' is not the correct word... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: 1) Json.NET supports dynamic object that implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.  See [Serialization Guide: Dynamic](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Dynamic).  Perhaps the 3rd party library did something wrong there?  2) Perhaps there is something wrong with your [`DefaultSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/p_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_defaultsettings.htm).   Try setting them to null before serializing.

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried using `var` instead of `dynamic`?

```
// Use "var" in the declaration below.
var requirements = order.Title.Commitments[0].Requirements;
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requirements);
```

When you only want to deserialize `requirements` without doing anything else with it then there is no need to use it `dynamic`ally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got the same JSON, with only the IDs.. Any other idea?

Comment: Yeah, talk to the guys that maintain that 3rd party library. My guess is they made a mistake when subclassing `DynamicObject`.

Comment: This is what I think too... I emailed them, let's see.. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: And did you check what does 'var' actually mean to the compiler??

Answer (score 6):

Try using Convert.ToString() as following code to convert 'dynamic' object to 'string' -

```
dynamic order = (dynamic)orderFound;
dynamic requirements = order.Title.Commitments[0].Requirements;
string validString = Convert.ToString(requirements);
```

Comment: This works great in ASP.NET where `var` cannot be used