# Converting dynamic to json (anonymous)

Tags: c#

I have a `dynamic` object that I have to convert to `json` (anonymous) for passing to an API as param. What is the best way to do this conversion?

There is this post:

[How to convert a dynamic object to JSON string c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825113/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-object-to-json-string-c)

But this does not quite apply to me as I cannot use `var` as explained in the comment below.

Thanks
Anand

Trying to covert

```
 dynamic d = new ExpandoObject()
 d.prop = "value"
```

To:

```
var json = new {prop = "value"}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825113/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-object-to-json-string-c

Comment: I have seen this post but I don't think it applies to my case. I cannot use var to start with as I have to add properties on the fly after creation.

Comment: If you need JSON why are you creating a dynamic object? If you have `{"prop" = "value"}` just parse it.

Comment: Yes I did it this way: with  `param as Dictionary<string, object>` i serialized `var payloadRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
            var json = JObject.Parse(payloadRequest);`

Answer (score 2):

If you are in `.NET Core` You can use `System.Text.Json;`and serialize as `dynamic`

```
public static void Main()
{
    dynamic w = new ExpandoObject() { Date = DateTime.Now, Item1 = 30 };
    w.Item2 = 123;
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<dynamic>(w));
}

class ExpandoObject
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public int Item1 { get; set; }
    public int Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

[fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tkvJsR)

But I do not understand why do you need to use `dynamic` (probably there is some logic behind it)

if you are in `.Net Framework` you need to use [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which is basically the same stuff

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<dynamic>(w);
```